Interesting problem of probability theory about σ-algebras
Task:
Let $\Omega$ be the set of all possible sequences $\omega = (\omega_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ consisting of zeros and ones. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\omega_{n}$ denotes the $n$-th coordinate of the sequence $\omega$.

Let $F_n$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first $n$ coordinates, i.e., $\sigma (\omega_{1}, \ldots , \omega_{n})$.
Let $G_n$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the coordinates starting from $n$, i.e., $\sigma(\omega_{n}, \omega_{n+1}, \ldots )$.

Define:

$F = \sigma (\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_{n})$, and
the residual $\sigma$-algebra $G = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} G_{n}$.

Suppose that the probability measure $P$ on $F$ is permutation-invariant, meaning that for any permutation $\pi$ that swaps a finite number of coordinates, the following holds:
$P(\pi (A)) = P(A)$ for all $A \in F$
Additionally, assume that the measure $P$ on $G$ is trivial, i.e., it only takes the values $0$ or $1$.
Prove that the $\sigma$-algebras $F_{n}$ are mutually independent.
I solved this problem like this, but my professor said it was inaccurate:
Choose a finite number of $\sigma$-algebras $F_{n_{1}}, F_{n_{2}}, \ldots , F_{n_{k}}$ and events $A_{i} \in F_{n_{i}}$ for each $i = 1, \ldots , k$. We need to prove: $P(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{k}) = P(A_{1}) \cdot P(A_{2}) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(A_{k})$.
Define the event: $B = A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{k}$. Consider a permutation of the coordinates such that the initial coordinates defining the events $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots , A_{k}$ are swapped with coordinates outside $n_{k}$. Since the measure $P$ is permutation-invariant, the event $B$ after such a permutation has the same probability.
After the permutation, the event $B$ becomes "independent" of the remaining coordinates because each permutation ensures that the initial events are independent of the tail. Using the triviality of the measure on the residual $\sigma$-algebra $G$, we conclude that the probability of $B$ equals the product of the probabilities of the individual events: $P(B) = P(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap \ldots \cap A_{k}) = P(A_{1}) \cdot P(A_{2}) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(A_{k})$. Thus, we have proven that the $\sigma$-algebras $F_{1}, F_{2}, \ldots$ are mutually independent as required. Proof complete.
Please can you correct what is wrong with my solution?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
